# getting 404 when consumiing spring controller service

Tags: java, html, spring, annotations, spring-3

I have created a spring application (**Spring version 3.2.8**). The application is working fine but the issue which I am facing is that when I try to consume the controller service through url I am getting 404 error

The url which I try to consume through browser url is given below, which I expect to return a `test` string

```
http://localhost/Spring3Sample/user/getPersonDetails
```

My code is as given below

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" 
          p:prefix="/" p:suffix=".jsp" />
</beans>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.controllers" />

</beans>
```

**UserController.java**

```
package com.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    private static final String APP_JSON = "application/json";

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getPersonDetails", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = APP_JSON)
    public String getPersonDetails() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>Spring3Sample</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

**UPDATE 1**

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
    <display-name>Spring3Sample</display-name>
:
:
:
```

Comment: Do u want this to be return as *Text in response body* ? If yes then add `@ResponseBody` on ur controller's method.

Comment: @OO7 That's not going to help if the request is already 404ing...

Comment: I'm not sure if it's related, but you should look into using the servlet 3 spec and therefore also update your `web.xml` to use `xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0"`

Comment: See u have mapped servlet with `<url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>`.  Access the page again by adding `.do` URL pattern like `http://localhost/Spring3Sample/user/getPersonDetails.do`. Since, u haven't mentioned `.do` the mapping of resources is not done & hence u get `HTTP Status 404`.

Comment: @beerbajay I have updated my web.xml, check my update still getting 404

Comment: @OO7  I have updated my web.xml like what beerbajay said, also tried tried with.do like `http://localhost/Spring3Sample/user/getPersonDetails.do` but still the same 404 error

Comment: @AlexMan Can you provide your client side code from where you called this REST call

Comment: Do u missed to add port number in the URL ?

Comment: @OO7 I am using apache server and port number is 8080

Comment: Thats what I want. Please add `8080` port after localhost like `http://localhost:8080/Spring3Sample/user/getPersonDetails.do`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mapped the `DispatcherServlet` with URL pattern as

```
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Whenever you want t request a controller method you must have to add this URL pattern to the request. So that Spring will find the correct mapping this.

So **change your request URL** to following:-

```
http://localhost:8080/Spring3Sample/user/getPersonDetails.do
```

**As you expect to return a *test* string:**

Add the

```
@ResponseBody
```

annotation to ur controller's method. So that Spring wouldn't look for the JSP page with name `test`, instead return `test` as String.

**EDIT:**

**From the discussion in chat:**

Also u are missing `<mvc:annotation-driven /> in applicationContext.xml`.

**To remove `*.do` from the request URL:**

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I am getting `Unable to connect` when I tried with `http://localhost:8080/Spring3Sample/user/getPersonDetails.do` but when I tried with `http://localhost/Spring3Sample/user/getPersonDetails.do` atleast I am getting 404

Comment: Restart the `Apache Server` & try again & check whether u get the same error.

Comment: restarted and tried.....I don't know what is the problem behind this, do I need to do any other modifications

Comment: Can u show the complete `HTTP Status 404` which u get while accessing this page ?

Comment: How did call this method ? Is it `GET` or `POST` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77089/discussion-between-oo7-and-alex-man).

Answer (score 2):

After observing  your applicationContext.xml , I can see you are missing `<mvc:annotation-driven/>`  Your Updated code will look like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd"
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">                                            

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.controllers" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>  

</beans>
```

> Explanation

`<annotation-driven />` means that you can define spring beans dependencies without actually having to specify a bunch of elements in xml or implement an interface or extend a base class.Means @Controller tells spring that the the class specified contains methods that will handle http requests without you having to implement the Controller interface or extend a subclass that implements controller.

`<context:component-scan base-package="com.controllers" />` tells spring that it should search the class path for all the classes under `com.controllers` and look at each class to see if it has a @Controller, or @Repository, or @Service, or @Component and if it does then Spring will register the class with the bean factory as if you have defined in  in the xml configuration files

**As per user comment**

> do we need both applicationContext.xml and dispatcher-servlet.xml

Actually Spring lets you define multiple contexts in a parent-child hierarchy.

`applicationContext.xml` defines the beans for the root webapp context means the context associated with the webapp.

`dispatcher-servlet.xml` defines the beans for one servlet's  application context. There can be many `dispatcher-servlet.xml` in a webapp  i.e servlet1-servlet.xml for servlet spring1, spring2-servlet.xml for servlet spring2

> note:: Beans in spring-servlet.xml can reference beans in
>   applicationContext.xml, but not vice versa.

Comment: do we need both applicationContext.xml and dispatcher-servlet.xml

Comment: normally  the applicationContext.xml context is unnecessary. It is generally used to contain beans that are shared between all servlets in a webapp. If you only have one servlet, then there's not really much point, unless you have a specific use for it. see my updated answer for more explanation

Comment: can we remove that.do extension

Comment: yes , but then your  browser url  with any extension   like /getPersonDetails.do or /getPersonDetails.htm or /getPersonDetails.123 can access same controller see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29778130/spring-controller-request-mapping-issue-for-dot-in-resource/29779554#29779554 for more detail

Answer (score 1):

- You missed port number in your URL
- Use this URL
  http://localhost:8080/Spring3Sample/user/getPersonDetails

Comment: Check whether your server is running or not??

Comment: I am getting Unable to connect when I tried with http://localhost:8080/Spring3Sample/user/getPersonDetails but when I tried with http://localhost/Spring3Sample/user/getPersonDetails.do atleast I am getting 404

Comment: server is running fine

Comment: Restart server or fresh install Tomcat and check

Comment: restarted and tried.....I don't know what is the problem behind this, do I need to do any other modifications

Comment: Make sure Tomcat is running on a port that is not being used in that moment by another program or service. It may be necessary to change Tomcat’s port which is 8080 by default. Skype and many other programs also attempt to use port 8080. If you are having problems, change Tomcat’s port to be safe.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77088/discussion-between-ranjeet-and-alex-man).

Answer (score 1):

First in Spring MVC manual

> The @Controller annotation acts as a stereotype for the annotated
>   class, indicating its role. The dispatcher scans such annotated
>   classes for mapped methods and detects @RequestMapping annotations
>   (see the next section).

So delete this

```
@RequestMapping("/user")
```

Because it makes no sense next

```
@RequestMapping("/user/getPersonDetails")
```

you should note I add "/user" to url.
Also you are not return any jSon. First if I were you I change second request mapping (on the method getUserDetails) with string I put in this answer.

And looks like you miss with config files...
Check this string in web.xml

```
<url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
```

it will dispatch only urls with ".do" at their end.

Answer (score 1):

I added this to my config class that extends `WebMvcConfigurer`:

```
  @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        final InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

        bean.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/pages/");
        bean.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return bean;
    }
```

You'll have to add this dependency for it to work:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```